# Binary search exiting early?

Tags: javascript, binary-search

I'm trying to find the duplicates of two arrays and one of the arrays is significantly larger so I'm iterating through the smaller array while doing a binary search on the larger array for the number. However, my solution isn't running.

```
function bSearch(arr, num) {
  let start = 0
  let end = arr1.length - 1
  while (start <= end) {
    let middle = Math.round(start + end / 2)
    if (arr[middle] === num) {
      return arr[middle]
    } else if (arr[middle] < num) {
      start = middle
    } else {
      end = middle
    }
  }
  return false
}

function dup(arr1, arr2) {
  let output = []
  let shorterArray = arr1.length > arr2.length ? arr2 : arr1
  for (let i = 0; i < shorterArray.length; i++) {
    if (bSearch(arr1, shorterArray[i])) {
      output.push(shorterArray[i])
    }
  }
  return output
}

let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7], arr2 = [3, 6, 7, 8, 20]
dup(arr1, arr2)

// should return [3, 5, 7]
// currently only returns [3]
```

Comment: surely you mean it should return 3, 6, 7?

Comment: `Math.round(start + end / 2)` I'm not sure this is doing what you think.  You might want to confirm the order of operations here.

Comment: your code actually causes an infinite loop

Comment: Also, if you find that `arr[middle] < num` you shouldn't set `start` to `middle`, but rather `middle +1`

Comment: `arr2.filter((s => it => s.has(it))(new Set(arr1))` is probably easier and has the same speed. ...

Comment: @MarkMeyer why do you set it to middle + 1?

Comment: @JorahFriendzone because you know `arr[middle]` is too low — it can't be in the solution because you've just tested that `arr[middle] < num` and found true.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Ah, yeah makes sense! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A number of small issues here.

1. `bSearch(arr1, shorterArray[i])` - in case of `arr1` being short you search only it.
2. In your binary search you use the length of `arr1`, not `arr` for intial `end` variable declarion.
3. `let middle = Math.round(start + end / 2)` - `.round()` rounds different ways, use `.floor()`.
4. `Math.round((start + end) / 2` - `start` and `end` addition should be in brackets
5. Binary logic should increase or decrease middle, otherwise you end up in infinite loop i.e `(6 + 6)/2 === 6`

Thus:

```
if (arr[middle] === num) {
    return arr[middle]
} else if (arr[middle] < num) {
    start = middle + 1
} else {
    end = middle - 1
}
```

JsBin: https://jsbin.com/ciyusodisi/edit?js,console